# Can't center main menu links IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, center

I've been working on a project for a while now and things were going great, but then I realized that my code didn't work at all in IE. I'm trying to fix a few main things, and give up on some things, but there's one thing that I can't seem to make work in IE. (Bear with me; this is a school project.)

My plan is to have 5 image buttons/links aligned in the center of the page. I've made each link into a link with a background image because I wanted to add a hover effect...

This is my code for the menu:

```
<a href="profile.html" id="profilebtn"><br><br><br><p>Profile</p></a>
<a href="projects.html" id="projectsbtn"><br><br><br><p>Projects</p></a>
<a href="gallery.html" id="gallerybtn"><br><br><br><p>Gallery</p></a>
<a href="blog.html" id="blogbtn"><br><br><br><p>Blog</p></a>
<a href="contacts.html" id="contactsbtn"><br><br><br><p>contacts</p></a>
```

This is my css that works in FireFox and Chrome (and Safari):

```css
#profilebtn, #projectsbtn, #blogbtn, #gallerybtn, #contactsbtn {
    font-family: 'courier New', monospaced;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#profilebtn {
    background-image: url(images/Profilebutton.png);
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 670px;
    text-align: right;
}
#profilebtn:hover {
    background-image: url(images/profilehover.png);
}
#projectsbtn {
    background-image: url(images/projectsbutton.png);
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 335px;
    text-align: right;
}
#projectsbtn:hover {
    background-image: url(images/projectshover.png);
}
#gallerybtn {
    background-image: url(images/gallerybutton.png);
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#gallerybtn:hover {
    background-image: url(images/galleryhover.png);
}
#blogbtn {
    background-image: url(images/blogbutton.png);
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 335px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#blogbtn:hover {
    background-image: url(images/bloghover.png);
}
#contactsbtn {
    background-image: url(images/contactsbutton.png);
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 670px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#contactsbtn:hover {
    background-image: url(images/contactshover.png);
}
```

This is the link [here](http://10284.itec.westlakegirls.school.nz/InnerIsland/).

Comment: what's the version of your IE?

Comment: Working same for me in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Why are you absolute positioning your Nav items???

Comment: Also, you are using Br points to position your <p>, why not set your nav within a ul, with display: inline-block, then set the images in a div with pos: absolute , with your p pos: relative with a bottom: 0; then everything will center perfectly with UL set with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: @Cam do i have to make it into an image like the answer i got from George? if not, it sounds really useful!

Comment: No text as an image is an awful idea.

Comment: oh... then i might as well try your opinion first. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my tests it works with IE8 and above. IE7 isn't supported by Microsoft anymore so rightfully you shouldn't have to worry about it, but that doesn't solves your problem if your teacher will be using IE7.

An easier solution might be to open up photoshop and put the text in the images. Then you can just do something like this:

```
<p><a href="profile.html" id="profile-button" class="button"><span class="button-text">Profile</span></a></p>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.button {
    width: 143px;
    height: 143px;
    position: absolute;
}

.button-text {
    display: none;
}

#profile-button {
    background-image: url("images/Profilebutton.png");
    left: 0;
    right: 670px;
}
```

This should degrade nicely and also avoids the need for all the `<br>` tags.

Comment: this might be easier than what i have already. thanks! ill give it a try!

Comment: Here are 2 reasons to never use text as an image. One responsive. Almost all images in responsive are percentage based, if the image shrinks, so does your text making it un-readable. 2. Images are larger than using text, in essence you are causing your load time to be hampered.